# How do I change the date of all commits in a branch to now?

Tags: git

In certain cases I may want to mask the exact date and time of work done and would like to reset the dates on a collection of work without throwing away the commit history as a whole.

How can I rewrite the dates on all commits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked around a bit and found nothing answering this exact question. The easiest solution seems to be:

```
git filter-branch -f --env-filter 'GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="`date`"; GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="`date`"'
git push -f origin master
```

Comment: This will go much faster (twice as fast) if you set *both* variables in one pass: `git filter-branch --env-filter 'tmp=$(date); GIT_AUTHOR_DATE=$tmp GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=$tmp'`, for instance (untested). Note that this filters all commits reachable from the current branch, which may include commits reachable from other branches as well.

Comment: I'll do another iteration in a bit. My use case is just to filter a master branch in its entirety, so the reachability of commits from other branches is not really my concern.

Comment: Doing a single run is indeed a lot more convenient. Now if only I knew why the -f backup override was necessary…

Comment: The `-f` is required if and only if `refs/original/` exists. It tells `git filter-branch` to go ahead and blow away the existing `refs/original/` name-space.

Comment: Yeah, but the very first time I ran it it didn't exist and now it does. I'm not that up to speed with my git-refs.

Comment: The last step of any filter-branch is that it replaces the existing ref values (as if via `git update-ref`) with the mapped hashes into the copied commits. But instead of relying on reflogs to hold their previous values, it saves the original values into `refs/original/`, so that `refs/heads/master` becomes `refs/original/refs/heads/master`. So with or without `-f` you end up with a populated `refs/original/` name-space after the first filter. You're expected to remove these manually when you're satisfied with the result.